# Invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $v = v_1 + iv_2$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are real vectors. Show that if we view $A$ as defining a map $α$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$ into itself, then $α$ leaves the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ invariant.

I'm looking for hints of how I should approach this problem. I mean, do I need to go directly by somehow showing that $\alpha(v_1)$ and $\alpha(v_2)$ lies in subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ or differently?

Note, this problem appeared on chapter on eigenvalues and eigenvectors (how to find them), but I cannot see how I can use them here. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to interpret the context a little. Presumably $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, and induces a linear transformation on $V=\mathbb{R}^3$. This linear transformation has a possibly non-real eigenvalue $\lambda=a+ib$.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$, and let $v=v_1+iv_2$.

We want to show that $Av_1$ and $Av_2$ are each in the (real) subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$. So we want to show that $Av_1$ is a (real) linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and that $Av_2$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Calculate. We have $Av=\lambda v$. Thus
$$A(v_1+iv_2)=Av_1+iAv_2.\tag{1}$$
But also
$$A(v_1+iv_2)=(a+ib)(v_1+iv_2)= av_1-bv_2 +i(av_2+bv_1).\tag{2}$$
Look at the right-hand sides of (1) and (2). The real parts must be equal, and the imaginary parts must be equal.

We conclude that
$$Av_1=av_1-bv_2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad Av_2=bv_1+av_2.$$
 This yields the desired result.

Note that the argument works for any vector space over the reals.